# php script not working in windows mamp but works in a mac

Tags: php, mysql

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889", "root", "root", "test");
if(!$link){ echo "Não foi possível se conectar ao banco de dados"; exit;}

$profEmail = $_GET['profEmail'];
$profPass = $_GET['profPass'];

//   $jsonData = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM Professionals WHERE profEmail='$profEmail' AND profPass='$profPass'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
    $row = "Login invalid";
}
echo json_encode($row);
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? I'd suggest checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Per http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php  the port should be passed in as a 5th parameter, not attached to the host.

Comment: This php file is called by a XMLHttpRequest and works well in the MAMP version of the iMAC. I recently installed MAMP in windows 10 and the installation seems to be correct, and my mysql database is accessed by phpMyAdmin without problems. However, the application does not succeed in accessing it.

Comment: What happens when you try? Is it providing any messages? Have you checked for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)? "Does not succeed" is so generic that it's no help at all in troubleshooting.

Comment: I get no error. the XHR responseText just comes empty!

Comment: After a few modifications to the code it is still not working. There is no mysqli_connect error, neither mslli_error in the sql. The XMLhttpREQUEST status is 200 but the responseText is empty.  <?php
    // Conexão com a base de dados

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "MStest", 8889);
      if(!$link){ echo "Não foi possível se conectar ao banco de dados",mysqli_connect_error(); exit;} echo "Connect Successfully. Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link);

Comment: Check the response in the network tab. It looks like you should be getting some sort of echo. If not, echo line numbers to see what happens. If you still get nothing, check the server error logs.

Comment: No errors were found. On the javascript side XMLhttpREQUEST status is 200, the responseText seems to be empty because no text is visible but it has length=53. On the other hand, the application runs fine in the iMAC - MAMP.

Comment: If you click on the request in the network tab, then click the Response tab, what is there?

Comment: What do you mean by network tab?

Comment: In your browser, bring up the Developer Console, then click on the Network Tab. Find the request, click on it, then click on the Response tab that shows. up.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, I used the php script as a standalone page, removing the json_enconde part and displaying the result in that page. There was no errors , but instead of, for instance, "á" � is displayed. I presume this special chars are not processed by json? How tyo solve this?